# Prove $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ is residually finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

I've been working on Isaacs' *Algebra, a Graduate Course*, and I'm not sure if my following solution to problem 18.17 is correct. I'd be really grateful if someone could point out the flaws in the argument and help me correct my mistakes.

Here's the problem:

> Let $F\subseteq E$ be an algebraic extension (of possibly infinite degree). Let $G=\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$. Show that $G$ is ``residually  finite". In other words, show that the intersection of all normal subgroups of $G$ having finite index is trivial.

Here's my attempt:

First, observe that we may assume that $E$ is Galois over $F$. If not, since $\operatorname{Gal}(\operatorname{Fix}(G))=G$, we may work with $\operatorname{Fix}(G)$ instead of $F$. From the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $K_H=\operatorname{Fix}(H)$ is Galois over $F$. Further, if $|G:H|$ is finite, then, since $|G:H|=|K_H:F|$, we have that $K_H$ is a finite Galois extension of $F$. [EDIT: Due to the counter-example posted by **reuns** I think it's better to say something along the lines of: the Galois group of any finite dimensional intermediate Galois extension of $F$ is normal in $G$.]

Thus, in order to show that the intersection of normal subgroups of $G$ with finite index is trivial, it suffices to show that the composite field of all intermediate finite dimensional Galois extensions of $F$ is $E$. To that end, consider a set $\{\alpha_i\}$ which generates $E$ over $F$. Since $E$ is Galois over $F$, it is separable and normal over $F$. Let $F_i$ denote the splitting fields of $\operatorname{min}_F\alpha_i$ (the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_i$ over $F$). Clearly, these $F_i$ are Galois over $F$, finite dimensional, and sub-fields of $E$. Further, the composite field of all these $F_i$ must be $E$, and thus, we are done.

Comment: @reuns Thank you very much for your help! I can see why any finite index normal subgroup must be the Galois group of some finite intermediate Galois extension, but can we also show that they must be of the form $Gal(E/F_i)$? Unless I'm mistaken, I thought it would suffice to only show that the $Gal(E/F_i)$ is a finite index normal subgroup, for if their intersection is trivial, then their intersection with any other subgroups should also be trivial, right?

Comment: I think I have an example with the axiom of choice of a finite index subgroup which doesn't come from a finite extension: let $E=\Bbb{Q}(\bigcup_{p\ge 3\ prime} 
 \zeta_p),F=\Bbb{Q}(\bigcup_{p\ge 3} \zeta_p+\zeta_p^{-1})$. $G=Gal(E/F)\cong \prod_{p\ge 3} \Bbb{F}_2$, sending each $\zeta_p$ to $\zeta_p^{\pm 1}$, so $G$ is a $\Bbb{F}_2$-vector space, choose a basis $(b_j)_{j\in J}$ with $b_0$ the complex conjugaison and $b_p$ the automorphism $\zeta_p\to \zeta_p^{-1}$ and let
$H=span( (b_j)_{j\in J,\ j\ne 0})$, it has index $2$ and the subfield fixed by $H$ is $F$.

Comment: @reuns That is a very nice example! I think I should reword my original post a bit.